# Flow: required fields not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, laravel-elixir

i am using [flow](https://flow.org/en/) with React for properties validation.

```
import React from 'react';


type Props = {
    requireField?: boolean,
    // inputType: React.PropTypes.oneOf(['text', 'number', 
    'email']).isRequired,
    title: string,
    name: string,
    extraClass?: string,
    controlFunc?: func,
    placeholder?: string,
};

const SingleInput = (props) => {

    var requireField;
    if( props.requireField ) {
       requireField = (<span className="text-error">*</span>);
    }

    return (
    <div className="form-group">
        <label className="form-label">{props.title} {requireField}</label>
        <input
            className={["form-control", props.extraClass].join(' ')}
            name={props.name}
            type={props.inputType}
            value={props.content}
            onChange={props.controlFunc}
            placeholder={props.placeholder} />
    </div>
    );
};
```

But when i use this component in my App, it should generates error because of wrong typed data:

```
<SingleInput
   requireField={true}
   inputType={'text'}
   title={20}           // -> this typed should generates error
   name={'first_name'}
   placeholder={'Your first name'} />
```

But i am not getting error, seems i implemented it wrongly. I tried with other other method like :

```
const SingleInput = (props: {title: string, .......}) => {
```

But not working as expected, please let me know what's wrong i have done in my codes?

I am using laravel-elixir with following package dependencies.

```
"devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.15.2",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1", // -> also holds "babel-preset-flow": "^6.23.0",
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0-alpha.6",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "laravel-mix": "^0.8.8",
    "lodash": "^4.16.2",
    "vue": "^2.0.1"
},
```

Comment: Please read tags description carefully before putting them in. [tag:elixir] is for tagging the beautiful language, that has _nothing_ to do with this.

Comment: @mudasobwa, was not aware of this, will take care. Thanks

Comment: Can you tell please how do you run `flow` checker exactly?

Comment: @GProst seems its not working with `laravel-elixir`, i tried command `yarn run flow`, and it will generates more errors, seems to configure the `.flowconfig` but can't success, don't even know if its the right way